# C# Как подключить сторонний словарь каких-то слов и рандомно вытянуть из него слово?

Tags: c#

Гуглил ничего не нашёл кроме создания пустого словаря Dictionary, но это мне не подходит.
Задача выглядит следующим образом.

Условно, мне нужно 2 словаря слов, первый содержит существительные, второй глаголы. Их необходимо рандомно вытащить из словарей и склеить в виде "Вкусно кушать".

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И мы конечно должны гадать, гдеж эти "сторонние словари" у вас, да? Ну берите простые текстовые файлы, пишите в них построчно все нужные слова, далее делаете `File.ReadAllLines("...")`, получая данные из файла, далее берете случайное значение по индексу (`Random` в помощь), ну и выводите на экран, готово. Зачем вам `Dictionary` я тут не совсем понял, как и не понял от куда всеж вы собираетесь подключать.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать ваш вариант.

Comment: Но ведь "вкусно" это не существительное

Comment: верно, но я же говорю, что это условно.
Кстати, всё получилось)